Align content relative to checkbox using css
I want to place checkbox and paragraph tag on same line for that using this code


.checkbox-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.checkbox-container input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin-right: 8px;
  /* Optional: Add space between checkbox and paragraph */
}
<div class="checkbox-container">
  <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox">
  <p>This is a paragraph next to a checkbox.This is a paragraph next to a checkbox.This is a paragraph next to a checkbox.This is a paragraph next to a checkbox.This is a paragraph next to a checkbox.This is a paragraph next to a checkbox.This is a paragraph
    next to a checkbox.</p>
</div>



output is like this

Here i want to start next line from starting as shown in image

Any solution Thanks

"output is like this" - and what about that is not how you want it? Other than that you manually added those red lines, the second image looks quite identical?

@CBroe Can you please check again i added screenshot in second line i need letters to start from initial position

Then using flexbox on the container is of course completely the wrong choice.

What you could do is to change the <p> tag to display: inline, this way both inline element will merge into the same line.


.checkbox-container p {
  display: inline;
  margin-inline-start: 8px;
}
<div class="checkbox-container">
  <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox">
  <p>This is a paragraph next to a checkbox.This is a paragraph next to a checkbox.This is a paragraph next to a checkbox.This is a paragraph next to a checkbox.This is a paragraph next to a checkbox.This is a paragraph next to a checkbox.This is a paragraph
    next to a checkbox.</p>
</div>



A proper way is to change the <p> tag to <label>, and assign the for attribute to the same id of the <input>, this way they are at the same line by default, clicking the text will toggle the checkbox automatically as well.


.checkbox-container input[type='checkbox'] {
  margin-inline-end: 8px;
}
<div class="checkbox-container">
  <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox">
  <label for="myCheckbox">This is a paragraph next to a checkbox.This is a paragraph next to a checkbox.This is a paragraph next to a checkbox.This is a paragraph next to a checkbox.This is a paragraph next to a checkbox.This is a paragraph next to a checkbox.This is a paragraph
    next to a checkbox.</label>
</div>




Thanks it's working can you pls let me know if we can add some space between checkbox and paragraph tag

You can still add some horizontal spacing by adding margin-right: 8px (or margin-inline-end) to the <input>. As shown in the updated answer.
